# Point Cloud Library viewer coordinate system changes every run

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds, viewer

Trying to capture some images from the 3D viewer in the Point Cloud Library. My issue is, I'll open the viewer, manipulate the camera to the proper position, then record the camera position and view angles, then in my code I'll set the camera position to the recorded values. However, the view I get the next time I run my program doesn't match with the view I had when I recorded the camera position. Is this something within PCL that I'm missing or something in my code?

Another issue I'm having is that the 3D viewer doesn't actually display anything unless I interact with it using the mouse (either dragging it around in the window or zooming in/out). I'd like to automate this process so this is a bit inconvenient. Relevant code:

```
boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> simpleVis (pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr cloud)
{

    boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer (new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer ("3D Viewer"));
    viewer->setBackgroundColor (0, 0, 0);
    viewer->addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> (cloud, "sample cloud");
    viewer->setPointCloudRenderingProperties (pcl::visualization::PCL_VISUALIZER_POINT_SIZE, 1, "sample cloud");
    viewer->addCoordinateSystem (1.0);
    viewer->initCameraParameters ();
    return (viewer);
}

int main() {
    outputCloud->width = (int) outputCloud->points.size();
    outputCloud->height = 1;
    boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer =                     
    simpleVis(outputCloud);
    std::string outName = generateOutputName("cross");
    viewer->setCameraPosition(3283.64, 4997.91, 2367.14, 0, -.3, 1);
    while (!viewer->wasStopped ())
    {
        viewer->spinOnce (100);
        boost::this_thread::sleep (boost::posix_time::microseconds (100000));
    }
    viewer->saveScreenshot(outName);
}
```

This code is pretty much taken directly from the PCL tutorials except for the setCameraPosition line which I added in, so I'm not entirely sure what could be going wrong.